# How to make a Android TV app with studio

Tags: android, android-tv

How to make a Android TV app without using leanback lib in studio. I don't want to use lean back lib UI, I need a custom UI. How to make it without using lean back. I dont want to put my app on TV play store. Can any one please guide me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can follow this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-android-tv--cms-23251

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a TV app in Android Studio without using the Leanback library. It can be built with the same layout as a regular Android app.

Just build the app like you would normally and add a launcher intent in your main activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```